# Is it okay to bring a bottle of champagne on an airplane (as checkin luggage)?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, regulations, airport-security

Can you bring a bottle of champagne with you as luggage (not as hand luggage)? Or would the pressure pose a risk and as a result not be allowed?

Comment: Even if it did explode, itd just get all over the inside of your bag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Considering champagne is a non-flammable liquid, the TSA apparently [allows it](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/prohibited-items) as checked luggage.

And this doesn't really surprise me. A bottle of Pepsi, deodorant spray and even compressed gas canisters are all ok to check in.