# Is it allowed and advisable to transport beer in checked luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, regulations, alcohol

I'd like to transport a six-pack of local beer from Canada to France. The amount of alcohol falls well below the amount I'm legally allowed to bring into Europe. My question concerns the logistics of transporting beer. I can't bring it in my carry-on since it's a liquid, and the simplest alternative seems to be to pack it in my suitcase (well cushioned in clothes to prevent breakage due to impacts/bumps). I'm concerned about the temperature of the baggage compartment, though. Will it be too cold, and cause the bottles to freeze and burst?

I'm flying Air Transat.

Comment: I'm going to leave this open since beer is often packed in aluminium cans, and that can have different methods of transportation than glass champagne bottles.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee - looks like the op agrees on the dupe

Answer (score 2):

Ah: [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10957/how-can-you-protect-a-fragile-object-like-bottle-of-champagne-in-your-baggage-ag) pretty well answers my question. I guess temperature isn't an issue. Breakage is, but that can be avoided by wrapping the bottles in t-shirts.

Comment: [Why shouldn't we use words such as 'here' and 'this' in textlinks?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100)