# How far in advance do you need to get to Quimper (UIP) airport?

Tags: france, airports, brittany, uip

As I understand it, [Quimper Airport (UIP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quimper_%E2%80%93_Cornouaille_Airport) is not exactly the world's largest or busiest airport. I'm not sure if it has [standing jokes about clearing sheep off the runway when needed, as Rotterdam does](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/19827986-post2.html), though I think it's even smaller than there!

When I check the online booking details for my flight, it helpfully just says:

> **Check In**: Detailed information not available
>
> **Gate closes**: 20 minutes before departure

I'm likely to be checking a bag on my return trip (with a few [bottles of local wine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10957/how-can-you-protect-a-fragile-object-like-bottle-of-champagne-in-your-baggage-ag) in it!), so I'm not sure I can just rock up at 21.5 minutes before! Would something closer to 30 minutes be enough with a checked bag, or will I need to arrive with a more "normal" airport timing to spare?

Comment: which airline, and domestic flight I assume?

Comment: heck, it does international flights - you're going back to LCY?

Comment: Note that 'gate closes' is likely the gate to the plane, not check-in.  You'll need to arrive with enough time to check in, go through security AND then get to the gate with 20 minutes to spare.

Comment: BA to LCY. I believe you pretty much walk through security and you're at the gate, and everyone else there will be going for the same plane, so I'm not expecting that bit to be the limiting part!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [french version](http://www.quimper.aeroport.fr/guide_enregistrement.php) of the airport website says:

> L'heure limite d'enregistrement est fixée à 20 minutes avant l'heure
>   du départ du vol pour les vols domestiques. Elle est portée à 40
>   minutes pour les vols européens.

So, check-in ends 20 min before flight departure for domestic flights, and 40 minutes before departure for european flights.
You can also try to call the airport at +33 2 98 94 30 30