# Airport security compatible container for small amounts of alcoholic spirits (drinks)?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airport-security

When travelling, I tend to find that the alcoholic spirits I like either aren't available, or are charged at some ridiculous markup that makes them unaffordable.

For a long trip, my usual solution is to pick up a bottle of something suitable from Duty Free on my way out, and pack what's left [carefully in my suitcase](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10957/how-can-you-protect-a-fragile-object-like-bottle-of-champagne-in-your-baggage-ag) for the return journey.

For a short trip, that approach presents two problems. Firstly, I wouldn't put much of a dent in a whole bottle, so I'd gradually accumulate 3/4 full bottles at home! Secondly, I often do short trips with hand luggage only, so I don't have a checked suitcase to put the bottle into.

I briefly tried finding "miniatures" (5cl bottles), and then later refilling, but generally the cap stops sealing properly after a few refils. Since these aren't that cheap to start with, to only get a few trips before they begin leaking means they're not a long term option.

Does anyone know of any good resealable / refillable containers, which can be taken through airport security, aren't too bulky, and are suitable for holding something like 5-20cl of alcoholic spirits (40%-ish)?

Comment: It seems like most airlines require alcohol to be in its original package: http://www.alcademics.com/2012/03/packing-booze-airline-liquor-regulations.html

Answer (score 8):

100 ml bottles are easy to come by, and food safe at that. Nalgene, for example, makes strong and well-sealing screw top bottles in a variety of sizes. The problem might be the lack of a label - make sure it reads 100 ml somewhere on it. (Or better still, 91.)

[image]

Comment: Food, maybe will be allowed. Liquids in such containers may not be allowed at some security checks. It would look suspicious since it is obvious that it is manually refilled.

Comment: I disagree. I have never once had anyone even consider checking whether what is in my (less than 100 m) bottle is factory-original or not. I use bottles like that for shampoo and no-one opens, smells, or investigates - ever.

Comment: Ok nice to know, I had a problem before with food in non-factory container. So I thought it might be a problem. Anyway TSA guys are not predictable and rules change so fast, one day it is not allowed the second day it is, and vice versa.

Comment: Same here. All my shampoo, soap, conditioner, handcream are in such bottle. I buy them @ Muji