# Is it possible to check Hong Kong duty free prices for alcohol online?

Tags: online-resources, hong-kong, duty-free

On an upcoming trip, I'm flying from London to Hong Kong, spending a few days there, then carrying onwards to Australia. I've generally found the arrivals duty free stores in Australia to be fairly poor value, so I'm therefore planning to buy things before I arrive.

One option is to buy things in Heathrow, then [pack it in my suitcase](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10957/how-can-you-protect-a-fragile-object-like-bottle-of-champagne-in-your-baggage-ag) while in Hong Kong, before flying on. The other is to buy things in Hong Kong before boarding my flight.

The [Heathrow duty free website](http://www.worlddutyfree.com/) isn't great, but it does manage to list the prices of many of the things they sell (but by no means all, or least not that I can find...) Fine for getting an idea though of prices, and pretty good on their special offers.

I've looked in the [Duty Free section of the Hong Kong airport](http://www.hongkongairport.com/eng/shopping/insideshopping/all/dutyf/list.html) website, which lists where the duty free shops are, but I can't seem to spot prices either there or linked from there. Since I'll be in HK second, if I discover Heathrow was cheaper it'll be too late...

Is it possible to check the rough or exact prices of duty free alcohol in the Hong Kong airport online? Or failing that, does anyone know roughly how prices compare with somewhere like Heathrow?

Comment: are yuur prices for liquor in hk dollars?

Answer (score 5):

You could try using the prices from a HK supermarket as a rough guide. Park N Shop is a pretty big chain (http://www.parknshop.com/WebShop/index.do); the other major one is Wellcome (http://www.wellcome.com.hk/wd2shop/en/html/index.html).

I can't remember what the situation is with taxes on alcohol in HK, but I think it'll be a pretty safe bet it'll be cheaper than Australia :)

**UPDATE**: It seems like there's no tax on alcohol under 30% in HK. There's some recent information in this thread (http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g294217-i1496-k6516896-Duty_Free_Alcohol-Hong_Kong.html), which has a link to this site too (http://www.dutyfreeaddict.com/search#/hong-kong) although I don't know how accurate it is.

Comment: Yes, the [gov. website](http://www.customs.gov.hk/en/passenger_clearance/duty_free/) confirms there is a tax on alcohol above 30% (60 proof).

Answer (score 2):

All that I could find was the price list that Cathay Pacific has for the [in-flight Duty Free shopping](http://www.cathaypacific.com/dutyfree/search.html?criteriaType=category&criteria=Fine%20Wines%20in%20the%20Air). This is however also very limited.