# Protect fragile items with biodegradable foam packing in a flight checked luggage

Tags: luggage, regulations, check-in, fragile-luggage, gate-check

Someone is planning to bring fragile items (eg. glass bottle, steel bar, lamp, or electronics without Lithium battery) in a flight checked luggage.

That person tries to protect those fragile items with biodegradable [foam peanuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foam_peanut) put them together inside the suitcase.

Which one is better: to spread those foams within the suitcase or to contain the foams into several transparent plastic bags before putting it into the suitcase?

This question emerge to overcome some cases when the airport security officers want to open the suitcase and do checking.

Thank you

Comment: Appologize to add a minor question (as probably it is an open question but still has a relation to the main question)
Is it allowable to bring biodegradable foams in a flight checkked luggage?

Comment: Steel bars are fragile? I mean, airline baggage handling can be rough, but it's rarely _that_ rough. Did you mean to write something else? 

Comment: Traveling between which countries? (in some countries almost all biodegradable materials are suspect and may likely not be imported, other countries will not be bothered by them.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks. It is 3D assembled thin steel bars. However, editor probably can remove steel bars to avoid confussion, please.

Comment: @Willeke Bedankt. I would say from UK to Indonesia for example.

Comment: I think an answer may change based on whether the luggage will be hard-sided or soft-sided luggage.

Comment: why the foam peanuts specifically? I am a big fan of wrapping delicate items in a cotton Tshirt (which I suppose is biodegradeable if that's important) as in https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/10962/46

Comment: Packing peanuts work best if the fragile item they are protecting is submerged in them. It'll be a nightmare for customs officers to check and for you to repack though.

Comment: @mkennedy Let say the person brings two suitcases, one hardcase and one softcase.

Comment: @KateGregory I am that cotton Tshirt methods fan too. Thanks. But I am affraid that the person will not bring any cloth in the suitcase.